# Normal at points of ellipse with given eccentric angles

Tags: conic-sections

If normals at the points of and ellipse whose eccentric angles are $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ and $\delta$ meet in a point, show that $\sin(\beta+\gamma) +\sin(\gamma+\alpha)+\sin(\alpha+\beta)$ = $0$

I started by writing normal equations in the parametric form at $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ and applied the condition of concurrency for the three lines but not getting the desired result.

Comment: where is $\delta$?

Comment: relation with respect to $\delta$ has not been asked
so i assumed that concurrency of three lines would be sufficient to get the desired relation

Comment: See the case of hyperbola [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3577046/concurrency-of-normals) as your reference.